# How to convert image results into data?

Tags: raytracing, 3d, model

I have made an 3d solar exposure analysis for a 3d city model that determines how long a surface receive direct sunlight throughout the year. Results are coloured surfaces and legend of coloures that explain how long the colour means. You can see the results in the attaching file. How can I report the results. How can I convert visualization into data? Because I want to query the results of analysis

[image: analysisi results]

Comment: If you coded the calculation wouldn't it be easier to query the data before it gets turned into colours?

Comment: I did not code it it is not an open source component I can not acces to surce code of 3d sun exposure component. But I want to convert result to data. Is it possible? Are there any component for this purpose? Or Do I have to code myself all workflows of analysis to achieve this?

Comment: I have closed the [older question](http://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/3582/reporting-results-of-3d-sun-exposure-analysis) as a duplicate of this one, since this one is more specific about what is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think getting the real data with high precision is not easy without some API.
The first idea would be just to manually use some color based selection tool that you can tell to select all areas in the screenshots according to the lookup table.
But that would not result in some 3D data, but only segmented images where you can annotate the values.

Another method would be to make a UV-map of the mesh, and then by making screenshots from various regions try to extract the color-coded texture.
Then you could read the interpolated color-values of the texture and map them back to the actual values.

The last but maybe strangest idea would be to make a huge number of screenshots and then use some multiview object reconstruction algorithm (I don't know if there is software or if you have to write it yourself.). There are algorithms that not only reconstruct the geometry, but also the texture.
This would then give you a model with the color-texture that again you could map back to the values.

But ideally there would be some export function in the software you used. Maybe this is a question you should ask the developer of the software. Maybe they have this function somehow but it is a bit hidden.